# Second Coat of Latex Stain

Tags: paint, stain

I stained my deck with Behr semi-transparent waterproofing wood stain.

It is NOT an oil based product.  It is more of a paint.

For the most part it worked well and the water is beading on the deck.

There are a few places where the stain is lighter colored and the water is not beading.  There are also places in the deck boards that are cracked and would like to coat the cracks a bit more.

What is a good technique for applying a second coat to the light spots?

For instance, do I need to sand first?

Answer (score 2):

I painted my deck last year with Behr stain, water based, but looked like paint because I wanted color. Later I noticed that some of the boards seemed like they didn't get as much coverage. So the next day I simply added a second coat on the spots and the boards where I felt it was too thin. It still looks great over a year later and I never had to deal with any sticky spots. I would just add a second coat after it is thoroughly dried on the spots you feel need a bit more.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

Some finish manufacturers have there recommendations on the can, whether it is a one coat product, or if 2 coats are recommended. If you place a second coat over a one coat product, chances are but not necessarily, going to create sticky spots.

If the first coat was just put in place and the directions say it can use a second coat, no sanding needed.

Comment: Please define "Just put in place".  It was stained about a week ago.

Comment: That constitutes just put in place to me. If it hasn't been walked and no dirt tracked onto it, or rained on a lot. Dirt in the atmosphere will eventually build up and keep the next coat from adhering.

Comment: The first question from the Manutius always, “Was it mixed properly?” and followed up with “Did you continue to mix it during the application?”